# neo4j/cypher: inline conversion of string to a map

Tags: neo4j, cypher

this might be obvious, but not to me:
I have a JSON object has a property that contains stringified JSON (don't ask why, it just has to be that way)
when I UNWIND the object and grab that property (key) is there a way to convert to a map inline to the cipher query?

```
WITH {input} AS S
UNWIND S AS stat
WITH stat.key.str as K, stat.value as value
UNWIND K as key
RETURN key, value
```

returns:

```
key                                                                          value    

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
{"role":"consumer","ipproto":"TCP","l7proto":"tcp:80","port":80,"dir":""}      156        
{"role":"consumer","ipproto":"TCP","l7proto":"tcp:443","port":443,"dir":""}    223        
{"role":"consumer","ipproto":"TCP","l7proto":"MSN","port":1863,"dir":""}    106208
```

is it possible to parse/load the string value in key to read it as a map or do I have to convert it outside the cypher query?

apologies - I am noob to both neo4j and cypher...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_from_tojson) for this, specifically `apoc.convert.fromJsonMap()` to convert it to a Cypher map. Here's how you would use it:

```
WITH {input} AS S
UNWIND S AS stat
WITH stat.key.str as K, stat.value as value
UNWIND K as key
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(key) as map, value
...
```